# Why are the MBR and GRUB present as files in the Linux filesystem?

Tags: filesystem

A computer's master boot record consists of raw binary and does not reside on any sort of partition. Legacy GRUB and GRUB 2 are installed to the sectors inbetween the end of the MBR and the start of the first partition. The boot code in the MBR, which is blind to filesystem formatting, loads GRUB from the no man's land residing after it. Why are the MBR (boot.img) and GRUB (core.img) accessible as files through the Linux filesystem?

Comment: Where in the filesystem do you find them?

Comment: `/boot/grub/i386-pc`

Answer (score 1):

First, in linux, everything is a file. Binaries and libs are all files.

Second, boot.img and core.img are not in your MBR. The MBR is the first part of your hard drive and contains the initial boot and partition table. The MBR then passes off the boot process to grub, which is located on your boot partition.

See

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Master_Boot_Record

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/02/linux-boot-process/

https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Images.html

From the last link

> boot.img
>
> On PC BIOS systems, this image is the first part of GRUB to start. It is written to a master boot record (MBR) or to the boot sector of a partition. Because a PC boot sector is 512 bytes, the size of this image is exactly 512 bytes.
>
> The sole function of boot.img is to read the first sector of the core image from a local disk and jump to it. Because of the size restriction, boot.img cannot understand any file system structure, so grub-setup hardcodes the location of the first sector of the core image into boot.img when installing GRUB.

and

> core.img
>
> This is the core image of GRUB. It is built dynamically from the kernel image and an arbitrary list of modules by the grub-mkimage program. Usually, it contains enough modules to access /boot/grub, and loads everything else (including menu handling, the ability to load target operating systems, and so on) from the file system at run-time. The modular design allows the core image to be kept small, since the areas of disk where it must be installed are often as small as 32KB.
>
> See BIOS installation, for details on where the core image can be installed on PC systems.

both boot.img and core.img are a part of the grub package and are stored in /boot, regardless as to if /boot is a separate partition from / or not

Comment: I didn't say that they both resided in the MBR. I said `boot.img` is the MBR.

Comment: boot.img is a part of the grub package and is copied (written) to the MBR when you install grub. If you over-write the MBR , boot.img will remain on your /boot partition but the system will not boot grub unless you restore it. You can delete, move, or rename boot.img and , unless you over write your MBR, the system will still boot grub.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean: `boot.img` contains the contents of the master boot record because that is its representation in file form. But neither it nor `core.img` reside in a partition, so that is why I'm asking why they appear in `/boot` since they don't need to.

Comment: boot.img != the contents of your MBR. Grub writes boot.img to part of your MBR when you install grub. You need to write this information to the MBR somehow, how would you have grub do it ? download a boot.img ? write a boot.img every time you install ? grub stores boot.img on your /boot partition and uses it when it writes your MBR.

Comment: "The MBR holds the information on how the logical partitions, containing file systems, are organized on that medium. Besides that, the MBR also contains executable code to function as a loader for the installed operating system" the executable code is boot.img, but boot.img =! the entire contents of your MBR. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Master_Boot_Record